# FDWaveformView: Set Play progress does not work

Tags: ios

I'm trying to set the play progress color of FDWaveformView as such after the waveform has been rendered and displayed:

```
-(void)endSliderDidChange
{
  self.waveformView.progressSamples = self.endSlider.value / 7.0 *  self.waveformView.totalSamples;  
}
```

I'm expecting to see the waveform before the slider in blue, and the waveform after the slider in grey - but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I've come to realize that there are myriad issues and bugs with FDWaveformView. For anyone reading this, drop FDWaveformView and go with SCWaveformView. It is infinitely better.
https://github.com/rFlex/SCWaveformView